# The derivative of $f(x)=\frac{3 \sin x}{2+\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

My solution:

**The background**

$$\begin{align} &3\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{2+\cos(x)}\right)\\
&=3\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(\sin(x))(2+\cos(x))-\frac{d}{dx}(2+\cos(x))\sin(x)}{(2+\cos(x))^2}\\
&=3\frac{\cos(x)(2+\cos(x))-(-\sin(x))\sin(x)}{(2+\cos(x))^2}\\
&=\frac{3+6\cos(x)}{(2+\cos(x))^2}\end{align}$$

However, I plugged $f(x)=\dfrac{3 \sin x}{2+\cos x}$ into the derivative calculator in wolfram alpha and received the following calculation:

$$\frac{3\left(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)+2\cos(x)\right)}{(2+\cos(x))^2}$$

Is my solution incorrect and the one from wolfram alpha correct? If so, where did I go wrong?

Comment: $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$.

Comment: I think your calculator can simplify its result to get yours.

Comment: Wolfram alpha asked for the [derivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+3*+sin%28x%29%2F%282%2Bcos%28x%29%29) and to [simplify the derivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+derivative+of+3*sin%28x%29%2F%282%2Bcos%28x%29%29)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Use trig. identity $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$

$$\therefore \frac{3(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)+2\cos(x))}{(2+\cos(x))^2}=\frac{3(1+2\cos(x))}{(2+\cos(x))^2}=\frac{3+6\cos(x)}{(2+\cos(x))^2}$$
Above matches your solution

Answer (score 0):

They are identical. The numerator of wolfram alpha

$$ 3\left(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)+2\cos(x)\right)$$
$$=3(1+2\cos x)= {3+6\cos(x)}$$

which is the same as the numerator of derivative  you correctly worked out.